# Using two dataframes but one Data Table

Tags: r, data.table

```
dataHAVE1=data.frame("student"=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                      "v1"=c('a','a','b','b','b'),
                    "v2"=c('b','a','a','a','b'),
                    "v3"=c('a','a','a',NA,'b'))



dataHAVE2=data.frame("student"=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                     "score"=c(4,6,7,1,3),
                     "class"=c(10,4,3,66,2))


dataWANT=data.frame("student"=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                    "score"=c(4,6,7,1,3),
                    "class"=c(10,4,3,66,2),
                    "v1x"=c(1,1,0,0,0),
                    "v2x"=c(0,1,1,1,0),
                    "v3x"=c(1,1,1,NA,0))




setDT(dataHAVE1)
dataHAVE2=cbind(dataHAVE2, dataHAVE1[, c("v1","v2","v3") := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.integer(x =='a')), .SDcols = paste0(c("v1","v2","v3"))]
```

I have 'dataHAVE1' and 'dataHAVE2'. I hope not to merge because these are such big files. I want to add v1-v3 from dataHAVE1 to dataHAVE2 but I want to clean them before adding them and I do not want to clean them in 'dataHAVE1' and then bring them over. The rule is: if v1-v3 = a then v1x-v3x = 1, if b then 0.

say this process were repeated but the new variables q1 and q2 depend on c1/f1 and c2/f2

```
dataHAVE1=data.frame("student"=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                     "c1"=c('a','a','b','b','b'),
                     "f1"=c('b','a','a','a','b'),
                     "c2"=c('b','b','a',NA,'b'),
                     "f2"=c('b','a','a','a','b'))



dataHAVE2=data.frame("student"=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                     "score"=c(4,6,7,1,3),
                     "class"=c(10,4,3,66,2))


dataWANT=data.frame("student"=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                    "score"=c(4,6,7,1,3),
                    "class"=c(10,4,3,66,2),
                    "q1"=c(2,2,1,1,0),
                    "q2"=c(0,1,1,1,0))
```

if c1 = a and f1 = b, q1 = 2

if c1 = a and f1 = a, q1 = 2

if c1 = b and f1 = a, q1 = 1

if c1 = b and f1 = b, q1 = 0

Here is output of d1;

```
> d1
  student q1 q2
1       1  2  0
2       2  2  1
3       3  1  2
4       4  1  0
5       5  0  0
>
```

---

```
library(data.table)
dataHAVE=data.frame("student"=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                     "class"=c('a','a','b','c','c'),
                     "qq1scorep"=c(1,1,1,0,0),
                     "qq1scoref"=c(0,1,0,1,0),
                     "qq2scorep"=c(0,0,0,NA,1),
                     "qq2scoref"=c(0,0,NA,NA,1),
                     "qq3scorep"=c(0,0,0,0,1),
                     "qq3scoref"=c(1,1,0,1,1),
                     "qq4scorep"=c(0,0,1,0,1),
                     "qq4scoref"=c(1,1,1,1,1))




dataWANT=data.frame("student"=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                     "class"=c('a','a','b','c','c'),
                     "score1"=c(2,2,2,1,0),
                     "score2"=c(0,0,0,NA,2),
                     "score3"=c(1,1,0,1,2),
                     "score4"=c(1,1,2,0,2))



setDT(dataWANT)[, c(paste0('score',1:4)):= dcast(melt(setDT(dataHAVE), 
                                             measure = patterns('^scorep\\d+', '^scoref\\d+'), 
                                             value.name = c('p', 'f'))[, q := fifelse(p == 0 & !is.na(c) & f %in% c(0,1), 2, 
                                                                              fifelse(p == 1 & !is.na(c) & f == 1 , 1, 0))], 
                                        student ~ paste0('score',1:4), 
                                        value.var = 'score', fill = 0)[, .c(paste0('score',1:4)]]
```

> Error: unexpected ']' in:
>   "                                        student ~ paste0('score',1:4), 
>                                           value.var = 'score', fill = 0)[, .c(paste0('score',1:4)]"

Comment: The issue `.c(paste0('score',1:4)`

Comment: Also, I see the `patterns` are not matching the column names `patterns('^scorep\\d+', '^scoref\\d+')`  it is looking scorep and one or more digits, but in `dataHAVE`, you don't have that pattern for columns

Comment: You need `setDT(dataWANT)[, c(paste0('score',1:4)):=dcast(melt(setDT(dataHAVE), 
                                             measure = patterns('scorep', 'scoref'), 
                                             value.name = c('p', 'f'))[, q := fifelse(p == 0 & !is.na(q) & f %in% c(0,1), 2, 
                                                                              fifelse(p == 1 & !is.na(q) & f == 1 , 1, 0))], student ~ paste0('score', variable), value.var = 'q', fill = 0)[, .SD, .SDcols = paste0('score', 1:4)]]`

Comment: how about creating lookup tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just assign (`:=`) the  subset of 'dataHAVE1' to `dataHAVE2` assuming the 'student' are the same in both datasets and in the same order

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dataHAVE2)[, paste0(names(dataHAVE1)[-1], "x") := lapply(dataHAVE1[-1], 
             function(x) +(x == 'a'))]
dataHAVE2
#   student score class v1x v2x v3x
#1:       1     4    10   1   0   1
#2:       2     6     4   1   1   1
#3:       3     7     3   0   1   1
#4:       4     1    66   0   1  NA
#5:       5     3     2   0   0   0
```

---

For the updated example

```
d1 <- dcast(melt(setDT(dataHAVE1), measure = patterns('^c\\d+', 
 '^f\\d+'), value.name = c('c', 'f'))[, q := fifelse(c == 'a' & 
  !is.na(c) &  f %in% c('a', 'b'), 2,
    fifelse(c == 'b' & !is.na(c) & f == 'a' , 1, 0))], 
     student ~ paste0("q", variable), value.var = 'q', fill = 0)

d1
#   student q1 q2
#1:       1  2  0
#2:       2  2  1
#3:       3  1  2
#4:       4  1  0
#5:       5  0  0



setDT(dataHAVE2)[, names(d1)[-1]:= d1[, .(q1, q2)]][]
#    student score class q1 q2
#1:       1     4    10  2  0
#2:       2     6     4  2  1
#3:       3     7     3  1  2
#4:       4     1    66  1  0
#5:       5     3     2  0  0
```

Comment: i get Error in `[.data.frame`(d1, , list(q1, q2)) : object 'q1' not found

Comment: @bvowe I checked again by running your example, it is not giving an error for me.  What is your `packageVersion('data.table')`

Comment: ‘1.12.8’ is the package version

Comment: @bvowe I have the same version.  strange

Comment: @bvowe Can you update your post with the output of 'd1'

Comment: the output of d1 is the same. i closed out r and then tried again and it worked. that was strange but not the first time i had to close out r...thank you for your incredible support.

Comment: @bvowe may be you defined an object 'd1' else where and it polluted

Comment: i think that may have happened--i tried to modify it so that  'd1' appends to dataHAVE2 but i can't get it to sync up, i am hoping not to create a new dataframe 'd1' but to add variables 'q1' 'q2' to dataHAVE2

Comment: @bvowe I just created the 'd1' just for understanding, you don't need to create 'd1' i.e. `setDT(dataHAVE2)[, names(d1)[-1]:= dcast(melt(setDT(dataHAVE1), measure = patterns('^c\\d+', 
 '^f\\d+'), value.name = c('c', 'f'))[, q := fifelse(c == 'a' & 
  !is.na(c) &  f %in% c('a', 'b'), 2,
    fifelse(c == 'b' & !is.na(c) & f == 'a' , 1, 0))], 
     student ~ paste0("q", variable), value.var = 'q', fill = 0)[, .(q1, q2)]]`

Comment: gotcha so then in the snippet you sent i would replace [,names(d1)[-1] with [,c("q1","q2")

Comment: @bvowe yes, sorry, that piece i forgot

Comment: @akron i am embarrassed but i am not able to modify this code for my exact data format, should i update this question or ask a new one? i usually post simple example and then i learn by modifying it to my exact problem, however i am unable to resolve it this time..

Comment: @bvowe What is the issue you are facing as I can't reproduce that issue

Comment: i added it to the bottom of the post